# Структуры и объединения в C++

Tags: c++, структуры, объединение

Что происходит в этом кусочке кода?

```
union
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned char speed:4;
        unsigned char stop: 1;
        unsigned char control:1;
        unsigned char parity:2;
    };
    unsigned char  byte;
} control;
*****

*****
control.speed = SPEED_2400;   // define равный 0001
control.stop = 1;
control.control  = 1;
control.parity = 1;
```

в смысле, я сейчас открываю для себя такую область в си, как структуры и объединения, вроде как разобрался, для чего нужно одно, для чего второе, и как ими обоими оперировать. Но о том, что происходит сверху я могу только догадываться, потому что:

> struct /*имя структуры*/ {   /*переменные-члены структуры*/ };
>
> union /*имя объединения*/ {   /*переменные-члены объединения*/ };

ну с чего бы начать.. мне тут всё непонятно. Допустим, почему имен у структуры и объединения нет, или тот control в конце сразу за двоих? и что он внизу то забыл? что за двоеточия и циферки после параметров?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В c/c++ типы могут быть заданы безымянными. Т.е. у самого типа имени не задано, но задано имя у переменной этого безымянного типа. В Вашем случае `control` как раз такое имя.

Двоеточия в данном случае говорят о том, что конкретный член используется как битовое поле. Цифра после двоеточия - это кол-во бит в этом битовом поле.

Весь же пример показывает возможность менять отдельные биты байта с именем `byte` через члены, являющиеся битовыми полями. Вытекает всё это из того факта, что в объединении (`union`) члены занимают общую память. Т.е. например мы пишем в `speed`, а фактически модифицируем 4 бита, принадлежащих в том числе и члену `byte`.

На основании [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487701/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-c#comment569805_487704) @gbg добавлю, что расположение и выравнивание битовых полей внутри класса (структуры) определяется реализацией.

Вырезка из Стандарта c++14, §9.6/1:

> Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is
>   implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is
>   implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable
>   allocation unit. [ Note: Bit-fields straddle allocation units on some
>   machines and not on others. Bit-fields are assigned right-to-left on
>   some machines, left-to-right on others. —end note ]

Т.о. в разных компиляторах может быть реализовано по-разному, и должно быть указано в документации к компилятору.

Comment: Только вот по стандарту C++ с этим связано столько граблей, что лучше так не делать.

Comment: @gbg что именно? желательно со сносками на Стандарт.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702658/c-union-array-and-vars - вот обсуждение на английском стеке, со всеми ссылками и прочим.